# Keep a program in full screen while opening a java application

Tags: java, swing

Scenario:

1. I run a Java program that paints something in a JPanel when a timer
   stops.
2. Then I open a PowerPoint presentation in full screen.
3. When my java app opens the JPanel (that is when the timer has
       stopped), the PowerPoint presentation exits full screen.

Problem: my PowerPoint goes out of full screen when I try to do this, but that's exactly what I don't want. I want to keep my PowerPoint presentation in full screen while my Java app is shown over it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "full screen" do you mean "full screen exclusive mode"?  Are you requesting focus or bringing the panel/window to the front?

Comment: *"my PowerPoint goes out of full screen when I try to do this"*  From your description, it seems as though PowerPoint does not 'play nice' with other apps. opening in front of it when in full screen mode.  That is probably something you'll have to take up with Microsoft.

Comment: I was talking about presentation mode in PowerPoint, and I just included the method setAlwaysOnTop() to the JFrame and seems to be working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the JFrame maximized by default in swing you can use `JFrame. setExtendedState()`, illusrated below:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{ 
   public WelcomeScreen() {

       // Other codes 

       // Set the JFrame to maximize by default on opening
       setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);        

       // Rest of the program
    }
}
```

Also remember that you should not have `JFrame.pack()` or `JFrame.setMaximimumSize()` or `JFrame.setSize()` in the same menthod (here constructor).